# validate fields with php and ajax and use sections

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am validating data from a form with php and ajax, and I find a problem, and that is that the php file sends the number of results to a javascript file, in which it does the verification, but I have a problem is that the php file sends the number of data from an `echo`, very rare and that is that I create the variable  `SESSION` and depending on the type of user I redirect to some page with the function `header ('location: ../ client.php')`, and what happens next is that the php file sends all the code of the page with the number of data found to the js file and This causes the validation to fail, so how could I solve this error since the redirection functions do not work.

codeajax

```
function iniciar_sesion() {
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "Php/iniciar_sesion.php",
    data: $('#formularioini').serialize(),
    success:function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      if (r>0) {
        $('#formularioini')[0].reset();
      } else {
        swal("¡Error al ingresar!", "identificacion y/o contraseña, incorrectos", "error");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

code php

```
$queryIniciar=Conexion::conectar()
                ->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM `usuarios` 
                            WHERE `IDENTIFICACION`=:nit 
                            AND `CLAVE`=:clave");
            
$queryIniciar->bindParam(':nit',$datos['nit'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryIniciar->bindParam(':clave',$datos['clave'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryIniciar->execute();
$resultados=$queryIniciar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['identificacion']=$resultados;
if($_SESSION['identificacion']['ID_USUARIO_FK']==1){
    header("location: ../administrador.php");
    exit;
}else if($_SESSION['identificacion']['ID_TIPO_USUARIO_FK']==2){
    header("location: ../cliente.php");
    exit;
}

echo $queryIniciar->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `echo $queryIniciar->rowCount();` is unreachable!

Secondly, as you are redirecting to another page whichever way you go through your IF statement and then `exit`ing, there is no actual point sending anything back to the calling javascript, as control will be switched to one of the redirected forms before you could do anything with it.

```
$queryIniciar=Conexion::conectar()
                ->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM `usuarios` 
                            WHERE `IDENTIFICACION`=:nit 
                            AND `CLAVE`=:clave");
            
$queryIniciar->bindParam(':nit',$datos['nit'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryIniciar->bindParam(':clave',$datos['clave'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryIniciar->execute();
$resultados=$queryIniciar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['identificacion']=$resultados;

if($_SESSION['identificacion']['ID_USUARIO_FK']==1){
    header("location: ../administrador.php");
    exit;
}else if($_SESSION['identificacion']['ID_TIPO_USUARIO_FK']==2){
    header("location: ../cliente.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Let's see if I understand, what you are telling me is that although the javascript captures the number of records, it cannot do anything since the page has already been replaced?